# Is there a way to stream results to driver without waiting for all partitions to complete execution?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Is there a way to stream results to the driver without waiting for all partitions to complete execution?

I am new to Spark so please point me in the right direction if there is a better approach. I would like to execute a large number of partitions in parallel and use spark to handle the distribution/restarts etc. As the operations complete, I would like to collect the results into a single archive in the driver.

### Use `toLocalIterator()`

I have been able to do this with `toLocalIterator()` which [according to the docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.RDD.toLocalIterator) limits the resources required by the driver. So it basically works.

The problem is that `toLocalIterator()` not only limits the driver to one partition at a time, but also seems to execute the partitions one at at time. This is not useful for me. The behavior is demonstrated in the demo code below.

### Use `persist()` + `count()` + `toLocalIterator()`

I found that I could somewhat get around this by persisting and then triggering parallel execution with a `count()`. After that, `toLocalIterator()` is able to pull pre-calculated results quickly.

The problem with this is that I have a large number of partitions (on the order of 10^3 or 10^4) that are sized to take about 15 minutes each. This ends up persisting a lot of data (not a big deal) but much worse, it seems to lose the persistence once the overall job goes on for too long. The partitions end up being recalculated. I'm using google dataproc with preemptible workers so that might have had something to do with it but I'm pretty sure it ended up recalculating even on the fixed workers... I'm not sure exactly what happened.

In any case, it's doesn't seem ideal to have to execute all partitions before having access to the first result.

The demo code below demonstrates the best case when everything persists well and iteration does not trigger recalculation.

### ??? --> iterate on the data without waiting for full execution

Is there anything like that?

### Copy/Paste demo code

```
import time
import pyspark.storagelevel

def slow_square(n):
    time.sleep(5)
    return n**2


with pyspark.SparkContext() as spark_context:
    numbers = spark_context.parallelize(range(4), 4)  # I think 4 is default executors locally
    squares = numbers.map(slow_square)

    # Use toLocalIterator()
    start = time.time()
    list(squares.toLocalIterator())
    print('toLocalIterator() took {:.1f} seconds (expected about 5)'.format(time.time() - start))
    # I get about 20s

    # Use count() to show that it's faster in parallel
    start = time.time()
    squares.count()
    print('count() took {:.1f} seconds (expected about 5)'.format(time.time() - start))
    # I get about 5s

    # Use persist() + count() + toLocalIterator()
    start = time.time()
    squares.persist(pyspark.storagelevel.StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)
    squares.count()
    list(squares.toLocalIterator())
    print('persisted toLocalIterator() took {:.1f} seconds (expected about 5)'.format(time.time() - start))
    # I get about 5s
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking this is not something you would normally do in Spark. Typically we try to limit amount of data which is passed through the driver to the minimum. There two main reasons for that:

- Passing data to the Spark driver can easily become a bottleneck in your application.
- Driver is effectively a single point of failure in batch applications.

In normal case you'd just let the job go on, write to the persistent storage and eventually apply further processing steps on the results.

If you want to be able to access the results iteratively you have a few options:

- Use Spark Streaming. Create a simple process which pushes data to the cluster and then collect each batch. It is simple, reliable, tested, and doesn't require any additional infrastructure.
- Process data using `foreach` / `foreachPartition` and push data to the external messaging system as it is produced and use another process to consume and write. This requires additional component but can be easier conceptually (you can use back pressure, buffer the results, separate merging logic from the driver to minimize the risk of the application failure).
- Hack Spark accumulators. Spark accumulators are updated when task has been finished so you process accumulated upcoming data in discrete batches.

  **Warning**: *Following code is just a proof-of-concept. It hasn't been properly tested and most likely is highly unreliable*.

  Example `AccumulatorParam` using [RXPy](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxPY)

  ```
  # results_param.py

  from rx.subjects import Subject
  from pyspark import AccumulatorParam, TaskContext

  class ResultsParam(AccumulatorParam, Subject):
      """An observable accumulator which collects task results"""
      def zero(self, v):
          return []

      def addInPlace(self, acc1, acc2):
          # This is executed on the workers so we have to
          # merge the results
          if (TaskContext.get() is not None and 
                  TaskContext().get().partitionId() is not None):
              acc1.extend(acc2)
              return acc1
          else:
              # This is executed on the driver so we discard the results
              # and publish to self instead
              for x in acc2:
                  self.on_next(x)
              return []
  ```

  Simple Spark application (Python 3.x):

  ```
  # main.py

  import time
  from pyspark import SparkContext, TaskContext

  sc = SparkContext(master="local[4]")
  sc.addPyFile("results_param.py")

  from results_param import ResultsParam

  # Define accumulator
  acc = sc.accumulator([], ResultsParam())

  # Dummy subscriber 
  acc.accum_param.subscribe(print)

  def process(x):
      """Identity proccess"""
      result = x
      acc.add([result])

      # Add some delay
      time.sleep(5)

      return result

  sc.parallelize(range(32), 8).foreach(process)
  ```

  This is relatively simple but there is a risk of overwhelming the driver if multiple tasks finish at the same time so you have to significantly oversubscribe driver resources (proportionally to the parallelism level and an expected size of the task result).
- Use Scala `runJob` directly (not Python friendly).

  Spark actually fetches the results asynchronously and it is not required to wait for all the data to be processed, as long as you don't care about the order. You can see for example [the implementation Scala `reduce`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/6c00c069e3c3f5904abd122cea1d56683031cca0/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.scala#L1007-L1028).

  It should be possible to use this mechanism to push partitions to the Python process as they come, but I haven't tried it yet.

Comment: I went through your information and it was very helpful. Each of the ideas you suggested would be a possible solution. I will probably eventually use message passing at the end of `foreach()` to get a fake streaming solution. Unfortunately my current data design is batch oriented so the direct streaming solution will not work. Once the data is reorganized, I will switch to the spark streaming solution. I decided against the accumulators since I read some concerns about consistency when there are failures. Thanks again!