# Exit a slow Spark map on a timeout, but preserve results so far

Tags: apache-spark

I am mapping over a Spark RDD, with a very expensive function (potentially tens of seconds per row).

It is possible that the job will take too long, and I will need to abort it to make way for other jobs in our data flow.

However, the results computed so far would still be useful to me, so I don't want to discard them, especially as they may have already taken hours to compute.

Is there a way to exit the transformation early, on a timeout, *but preserve the partial results computed so far*?

Comment: Related (but not the same as) to [Is there a way to stream results to driver without waiting for all partitions to complete execution?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41810032/8371915).

Answer (score 1):

There are at least a couple of ways to do this, by switching from `map` to a related transformation:

**mapPartitions**

`mapPartitions` gives us access to an iterator over each partition, so we can simply pretend there were no items in it, if the timeout has expired:

```
val data = sc.parallelize(1 to 100)

val timeout = 10000

val start = System.currentTimeMillis

data.repartition(10).mapPartitions { iter =>
  if (System.currentTimeMillis - start > timeout) Iterator.empty
  else iter.map(x => { Thread.sleep(500); x + 1 })
}.count
```

Depending on your environment, you may need to tweak the timeouts in this spark-shell example, but it should produce different numbers of results depending exactly when you run the transformation relative to setting `start`.

Note that there must be a significantly higher number of partitions than the total number of executor cores, otherwise all partitions will start immediately, and there's nothing to skip. Therefore, for this example, we explicitly re-partition the data before we start the `mapPartitions`. You might or might not need to do this, depending on the size of your data and the number of cores provisioned.

**flatMap**

A finer-grained approach is to use `flatMap`, which lets us process or skip each individual row conditionally, via a function that returns an `Option` (and just returns `None` if the timeout has expired);

```
// setup as before
data.flatMap{ x => if (System.currentTimeMillis - start > timeout) None
                   else Some({Thread.sleep(500); x + 1}) }.count
```

This approach doesn't require partitioning, but will scan over all the remaining partitions even after the timeout (but not perform the expensive processing on any of the rows).